# Using unsupported opcode (DMB) in Golang (for 32bit ARM)

Tags: assembly, go, arm, opcodes

I'm trying to issue a DMB instruction in a Go program, and I'm using asm function defined in a .s file. I'm compiling with Go 1.7.3 on an ARMv7 device.

DMB isn't a supported instruction in Go, but I see [documentation here](https://golang.org/doc/asm#unsupported_opcodes) on how to use unsupported opcodes.

Using some ARM gcc binutils, I found the opcode for DMB is f57ff05f. The `issue_dmb.s` file I have is below.

```
TEXT ·issue_dmb(SB),$0

    // DMB: opcode f57ff05f
    BYTE $0xF5; BYTE $0x7F; BYTE $0xF0; BYTE $0x5F

    RET
```

When I build, I get an error: unrecognized instruction "BYTE"

(Possibly related: I got the same error about `NOSPLIT` when I used this in the first line of the .s file as I see in many examples, so I removed it).

Am I missing something to get the assembler to recognise these keywords?

Comment: You might need to a 32-bit "word" size directive to emit the opcode because ARM doesn't have any 8-bit instructions, they're all 32-bits. That would also solve your other problem, that you've got the byte order backwards and 0xF57FF05F is 0x5F, 0xF0, 0x7F, 0xF5 in the little endian byte order that ARM uses.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it, using `WORD` directive instead of `BYTE`.